# Expected Gaussian distribution on screen in Stern-Gerlach Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

In the Stern-Gerlach experiment, they used a beam of silver atoms travelling in **z** direction (which has valence electron in the 5s shell), so the electrons carry zero angular momentum. Now since they have zero angular momentum, their magnetic moment must be zero. But when experiment was done by Stern and Gerlach, they expected a **gaussian** distribution because the magnetic moments were randomly oriented.

But my question is, even if the magnetic moments are randomly oriented, they're still zero, so if hypothetically there were no spin quantization, then we must get a single intense point on the screen because all the electrons must travel in same direction, undeflected by the spatially varying magnetic filed?

Answer (score 2):

The electrons do not have zero angular momentum; they have zero *orbital* angular momentum, meaning that the total angular momentum of the electrons (and to a good approximation, the silver atoms) is given by the *intrinsic* angular momentum (spin) of the electrons, which was assumed to be uniformly distributed across all directions. Thus, the magnetic moment is non-zero and proportional to the electron spin, causing the atoms to spread in the magnetic field.

Comment: What other experiment or calculations they did before the Stern-Gerlach experiment, which ket them know that there is some other non zero angular momentum in addition to orbital angular momentum? @Sandejo

Comment: @Shinekk: None, because they didn't know. They thought that the orbital angular momentum was non-zero.

Comment: You mean to say that, they thought $l=o$ state will have non zero angular momentum, against the hydrogen atom problem which suggested that $l=0$ state will have zero angular momentum? @Vercassivelaunos

Comment: @Shinekk: No, they thought the ground state was the $l=1$ state.

Comment: Okkk I got it. But with $l=1$ they must have expected three dots on screen and not gaussian distribution? @Vercassivelaunos

Comment: @Shinekk: Exactly, and they did expect that. So only seeing two dots was a surprise to them.

Answer (score 1):

Stern and Gerlach didn't know that electrons carry spin, so they did in fact think that their intrinsic magnetic moment is 0. But through experiments they still knew that the magnetic moment of a silver atom was non-zero. They attributed this to an orbital angular momentum with quantum number $l=1$, though, so they expected three dots on the screen (one each for the quantum numbers $m_l=-1,0,+1$), not two. So the reason for the classically expected Gaussian distribution at the time was a supposed orbital angular momentum.

Comment: They thought that valence electron in silver atom will not have $l=0$ state and will be in $ll=1$ state? @Vercassivelaunos